# Skip words / symbols when reading file

Tags: c#, vb.net, symbols, words

I'm making a small C# app and I have a small issue .

I have a .xml with plain text and I need only the 4th line .

```
string filename = "file.xml";
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    textBox1.Text += (lines[4]);
}
```

Till now everything is good, my only problem is that I have to remove from the 4th line some words and symbols .

My bad words and symbols :

```
word 1 
: 
' 
,
```

I'v been looking on google however I couldn't find anything for C#.
Found a code for VB , but I'm new in this and I really don't know how to convert it and make it working.

```
 Dim crlf$, badChars$, badChars2$, i, tt$
  crlf$ = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
  badChars$ = "\/:*?""<>|"           ' For Testing, no spaces
  badChars2$ = "\ / : * ? "" < > |"  ' For Display, has spaces

  ' Check for bad characters
For i = 1 To Len(tt$)
  If InStr(badChars$, Mid(tt$, i, 1)) <> 0 Then
    temp = MsgBox("A directory name may not contain any of the following" _
           & crlf$ & crlf$ & "     " & badChars2$, _
           vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
           "Bad Characters")
    Exit Sub
  End If
Next i
```

Thank you.

FIXED :)

```
 textBox1.Text += (lines[4]
              .Replace("Word 1", String.Empty)
            .Replace(":", String.Empty)
            .Replace("'", String.Empty)
            .Replace(",", String.Empty));
```

Comment: If your file is XML, you **really, really** should parse it as XML. Try `XDocument.Load`.

Comment: Checking string.Replace , Thanks.  --- The content for the XML is taken from WEB , a JS script .

Comment: You should accept the answer if it helped, not just mark the question as fixed... (it will give you 5 rep as well :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace them with nothing:

```
textBox1.Text += lines[4].Replace("word 1 ", string.Empty)
                         .Replace(":", string.Empty)
                         .Replace("'", string.Empty)
                         .Replace(",", string.Empty);
```

Or perhaps create an array of expressions you want removed, and replace them all with nothing.

```
string[] wordsToBeRemoved = { "word 1", ":", "'", "," };

string result = lines[4];
foreach (string toBeRemoved in wordsToBeRemoved) {
    result = result.Replace(toBeRemoved, string.Empty);
}
textBox1.Text += result;
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove space as well ?

Comment: @rgerculy Sure, just add `" "` to `wordsToBeRemoved`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Replace` to replace them with nothing:

```
textBox1.Text += (lines[4]
            .Replace("Word 1", String.Empty)
            .Replace(":", String.Empty)
            .Replace("'", String.Empty)
            .Replace(",", String.Empty));
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys gave good solutions, I just want to add another fast (using `StringBuilder`) and convenient (using Extension method syntax and `params` as values) solution

```
public static string RemoveStrings(this string str, params string[] strsToRemove)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder(str);
    strsToRemove.ToList().ForEach(v => builder.Replace(v, ""));
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

now you can

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
textBox1.Text += lines[4].RemoveStrings("word 1", ":", "'", ",");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I want something really simple to can understand my self too :)

Comment: @rgerculy there are 3 short lines of code in method implementation, how simpler can you get?

Comment: True ... but the second line " strsToRemove.ToList().ForEach(v => builder.Replace(v, "")); " is confusing me . I'm new, and I have to learn many things .

Comment: ok, I understand, there will be time, when you will grasp all the power of `LINQ`, my son. Let the power of Common Language Runtime be with you, young padavan.